Can we switch from 64-bit ia-32e mode back to 16-bit real mode step by step on x86 processor?
As we all know, we can use assembly code to make the x86 CPU that supports ia-32e mode step by step from the real mode to protected mode and then to ia-32e (64-bit mode).
However, many articles on the Internet tell us that it is almost impossible to switch back to real mode once the CPU enters ia-32e mode, and these articles give examples that the 64-bit version of Windows cannot execute 16-bit programs for this reason. But if so, how does 64-bit uefi achieve csm compatibility? Please teach me who is correct, thanks...

You can in fact switch from long mode back to real mode, although the bigger question is why do you want to do that?

Note: Intel is considering dropping legacy modes (real mode, 16/32 protected mode, v8086 mode) in future 64-bit processors.

@MichaelPetch Just curious, and it would be interesting if 64-bit Windows could run 16-bit programs directly. and There is a saying that 64-bit Windows cannot execute 16-bit programs because it is not allowed to enter v8086 mode in ia-32e mode. Is this true?

There is a difference between Windows 64-bit running 16-bit applications and dropping back to real mode running code and then switching back into 64-bit mode. You can run 16-bit code in a hypervisor guest or in an emulator. On 32-bit windows DOS compatibility layer was done via v8086 mode. v8086 mode is not available while running in compatibility mode or long mode, but you can switch the processor out of those modes into legacy protected mode. Whether there is a legacy BIOS present is a different story.

It is also possible in a multicore system to run long mode on one processor and be in real-mode on another.
